# Read Excel file from Share point office 365 in c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to read excel file from office 365 link.In this link, I can read and write records. Can anyone help how to access/read data from online excel file and update the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [graph api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/excel) to read excel file stored in SharePoint online.
Sample endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/drives/driveid/items/itemid/workbook
```